# How to select records where NOW is between two dates in fields?

Tags: mysql, php

I've searched all over for this, and I seem only to find how to get records where a single date is between two "outside" dates.

I want to find out how to select records where the current date is between the value in the startDate field and the value in the endDate field.

What I have so far (PHP):

```
$now = new DateTime();
$sql = "
    SELECT content, image, imageHeight, imageWidth, link, linkDescription 
    FROM news 
    WHERE appearanceDate < $now  
      AND $now < termDate 
    ORDER BY appearanceDate DESC
";
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `NOW()` function in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). Note, this assumes that `termDate` is the later date:

```
Select content, image, imageHeight, imageWidth, link, linkDescription
  From news
  Where appearanceDate < NOW() 
    And termDate > NOW()
  Order By appearanceDate Desc;
```

Comment: Actually I had a typo in my question which you propagated. It should be `Where appearanceDate < NOW()` ... my fault!

Comment: I have some date in $today variable and this works for me . $this->db->where(" G.start_date <= '$today' AND G.end_date >= '$today' ",NULL,FALSE);

Comment: [Now() in Laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/now-in-eloquent)

Answer (score 3):

If you want an *inclusive* range you can use the slightly nicer syntax afforded by [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

```
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN appearanceDate AND termDate
```

> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments are of the same type. Otherwise type conversion takes place according to the rules described in Section 13.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”, but applied to all the three arguments.

Answer (score -3):

You could use the MySQL `NOW()` function to get the current timestamp.